# Where is the webmvc-config.xml located in spring roo

Tags: spring-roo

I have created a spring roo application and it doesn't have a "webmvc-config.xm" located under "practice2\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF" . I am really stuck and i have no idea how to proceed .
I am using sprring 3.9.0 release, java 1.8,spring roo 2.0.0 rc1 .

Answer (score 0):

Spring Roo 2.0.0.RC1 generates standard Spring Boot applications, so will be really interesting that you check the Spring Boot documentation before to start to work with Spring Roo and Spring Boot.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/

Hope it helps,